# How to calculate $\int_{0}^{+\infty} {\sin {x^2}\mathrm{d}x}$?

Tags: calculus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Evaluating $\int_0^\infty \sin x^2\, dx$ with real methods?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/187729/evaluating-int-0-infty-sin-x2-dx-with-real-methods)

How to calculate $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{+\infty} {\sin {x^2}\mathrm{d}x}$ ?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/187729/evaluating-int-0-infty-sin-x2-dx-with-real-methods

Comment: have a look at this [Wolfram Alpha Solution](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integral%20from%200%20to%20infinity%20%28sin%20%28x%5E2%29%29)

Answer (score 2):

If you have some familiarity with complex analysis, this hint may be helpful:

Recall the Gaussian integral, defined $\forall \alpha \in \mathbb{R}: \int_0^\infty e^{-\alpha x^2} dx = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{4\alpha}}$.

Now consider $e^{ix^2} = \cos(x^2) + i \sin(x^2)$.  Naively, what does the above result suggest about the value of $\int_0^\infty e^{ix^2} dx$? If we take real and imaginary parts of the integral and its value, what would we find?

Most importantly, what contour integral in $\mathbb{C}$ would justify this? (think geometrically about what branch and value was chosen to "compute" $\sqrt{\frac{1}{-i}}$.)