# Trig Fresnel Integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals, fresnel-integrals

$$\int_{0}^{\infty }\sin(x^{2})dx$$

I'm confused with this integral because the square is on the x, not the whole function. How can I integrate it? Thank you.

I have not done complex analysis (only real analysis as I am a high school student) so how can I evaluate it using **elementary functions** (*without* complex analysis)?

Comment: I'm not sure, would $\dfrac{1}{x^2} \times (-cos(x^2))$ be correct?

Comment: This is called a Fresnel integral. The standard method to evaluate it uses complex analysis, but I am sure there are more elementary methods available if you Google for them.

Comment: @Aryabhata: I am not sure it is an *exact* duplicate. Unless I have missed something, the answer to the question being asked here cannot just be read off...

Comment: @Aryabhata It can be read off the very first sentence *so long as you know you need to use complex analysis*. So there is a leap. But I suppose that is covered by Potato's comment.

Comment: I edited my question.

Comment: @AlexanderJones: I suggest you just mention _without_ complex analysis.

Comment: I take back my close vote, as OP only wants real analysis methods.

Comment: Real method solutions can be found in answer to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/187729).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

$\displaystyle \int_{0}^{\infty}\sin(x^{2})dx$

Let $\displaystyle u=x^{2}, \;\ x=\sqrt{u}, \;\ dx=\frac{1}{2}u^{-1/2}du$

$\displaystyle\frac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin(u)}{\sqrt{u}}du$

Now, the Gamma function comes in handy:

$\displaystyle\frac{1}{2\Gamma(a)}\int_{0}^{\infty}z^{a-1}e^{-uz}\sin(u)dz$

But, since $a=1/2$, we have:

$\displaystyle\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-uz}\sin(u)}{\sqrt{z}}dudz$

$\displaystyle\frac{1}{2\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{z}(1+z^{2})}dz$

Let $t=\sqrt{z}$:

$\displaystyle\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{t^{4}+1}dt$

This is a rather famous integral and can be found here and there. I leave it's evaluation to the reader.

But, it evaluates to $\displaystyle \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\cdot \frac{\pi\sqrt{2}}{4}=\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{4}$, and so does the Fresnel in question.

Comment: I'm not completely following how you get equation 3 from equation 2.  Can you help me out?

Comment: It comes from the Gamma function. You can use this as a parameter in the integral.  $\frac{1}{u^{a}}=\frac{1}{\Gamma(a)}\int_{0}^{\infty}z^{a-1}e^{-uz}dz$

Comment: I follow now. Thanks!

Comment: An nice integration, if you're interested, is to derive $\int_{0}^{\infty}\cos(x^{a})dx, \;\ a>1$.  You can do it with Laplace transforms instead of the classic residue method.

Answer (score 3):

The integral does not have an elementary antiderivative. If you want to avoid complex analysis, try [this method.](http://www.math.binghamton.edu/loya/papers/LoyaMathMag.pdf)

Comment: Your link is dead

Comment: @user135711 Archive copy here: https://web.archive.org/web/20120524131816/http://www.math.binghamton.edu/loya/papers/LoyaMathMag.pdf