# Show that $\int_0^n\sin x^2dx$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, fresnel-integrals

**The question**

Okay. So I'm trying to solve the problem below for a previous exam in real analysis. Thus, only such methods may be used.

> The integral $\int_0^\infty\sin x^2dx$ is called a Fresnel integral and it arises in wave optics. Show that this integral converges, by proving that the sequence $a_n:=\int_0^n\sin x^2dx$ converges in $\mathbb{R}$.

The question also comes with the below hint.

> Hint: Use the fact that
>   $$
>  \sin x^2=-\frac{1}{2x}\frac{d}{dx}\cos x^2.
> $$

It makes me think of using integration by parts, and that has been the hint in similar questions. However, when I do that things don't get easier. Consequently, I'm kind of stuck.

Here are my computations

$$
 \int_0^n\sin x^2dx=-\int_0^n\frac{1}{2x}\frac{d}{dx}\cos x^2dx=[-\frac{1}{2x}\cos x^2]_0^n-\int_0^n\frac{1}{2x^2}\cos x^2dx.
$$

**Related questions**

There is a thread about evaluating the Fresnel integral called "[Evaluating $\int_0^\infty \sin x^2\, dx$ with real methods?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/187729/evaluating-int-0-infty-sin-x2-dx-with-real-methods)" and another one called "[Trig Fresnel Integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/378012/trig-fresnel-integral)", but none of the answers to these questions involve showing convergence as instructed in this question, and both involve the Gamma function, which wasn't included in my course on real analysis.

Comment: Integration by parts is the way to go.

Comment: Yeah, but I get stuck. I could add my computations for clarity.

Comment: The integrand on the RHS is bounded in magnitude by $1/2x^2$.

Comment: The last integral fails to converge near $x=0$ @Bungo

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Ah right, the integration starts at $0$, not $1$.

Comment: Just from the fact that $\int_0^n \sin(2 \pi x) dx$ converges doesn't imply that $\int_0^{\infty} \sin(2 \pi x) dx$ makes sense.

Comment: The trick is to replace $\cos x^2$ by $(-1+\cos x^2)$ in the formula you were given.

Comment: Okay. I’ll look at it when I come home.

Comment: @OskarTegby Of course, you could use your approach for the interval $[1, \infty)$, and then obviously $\int_0^1 \sin x^2$ converges since the integrand is bounded and continuous on the compact interval $[0,1]$.

Comment: Minor comment: The integral exists in an improper sense. The function is not absolutely integrable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without loss of generality, let $n>m$. Then,
$$ \left| a_n-a_m \right|=\left|\int_{m}^{n}\sin{x^2}dx  \right|= \left|  \int^{n}_{m} {-\frac{1}{2x}\frac{d}{dx}\cos{x^2}}dx\right|=\left|\left[-\frac{1}{2x}\cos{x^2}  \right]_{m}^{n}+\int_{m}^{n}-\frac{1}{2x^2}\cos{x^2}dx\right| $$

$$\leq  \left|\frac{1}{2m}\cos{m^2}-\frac{1}{2n}\cos{n^2}  \right|+ \int_{m}^{n} \left| \frac{1}{2x^2} \right| dx\leq   \frac{1}{2m}+\frac{1}{2n}-\frac{1}{2n}+\frac{1}{2m}=\frac{1}{m}\rightarrow 0   $$  as $n,m\rightarrow \infty$.

Thus, $a_n$ is Cauchy in $\mathbb{R}$ so there is $a\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $a_n\rightarrow a$.

Answer (score 1):

$$a_n=\frac12\int_0^{n^2}\sin y\frac{dy}{\sqrt y}
=\frac12\left[\frac{1-\cos y}{\sqrt y}\right]_0^{n^2}
+\frac14\int_0^n\frac{1-\cos y}{y^{3/2}}dy
\to\frac14\int_0^\infty\frac{1-\cos y}{y^{3/2}}dy.$$
This last integral is absolutely convergent.

Comment: In particular, for large $y$ the integrand $\sim y^{-3/2}$ has a $\sim y^{-1/2}$ antiderivative that vanishes at $\infty$, while for small $y$ the integrand $\sim y^{1/2}$ has a $\sim y^{3/2}$ antiderivative that vanishes at $0$.