# $\int^\infty_0 \frac{\cos(x)}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx$ Evaluate using Fresnel Integrals

Tags: real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

$\int^\infty_0 \frac{\cos(x)}{\sqrt{x}}\,dx$ Evaluate using Fresnel Integrals

(For reference the $\cos$ Fresnel integral is $\int^\infty_0 \cos(x^2)\, dx = \frac{\sqrt{2 \pi}}{4}$)

I've tried integration by parts but just ended up getting $-x\cos(x)$ for my final integration which doesn't help.

I suppose we want to some how get $\cos(u^2)$ into the integrand, but I'm stupid and can't figure out how.

Mathematica says the answer is $\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{2}$

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using Fresnel Integrals**

Substituting $x=u^2$, we get
$$
\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos(x)}{\sqrt{x}}\mathrm{d}x
=2\int_0^\infty\cos(u^2)\,\mathrm{d}u
$$
As shown in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/190293),
$$
\int_0^\infty\cos(u^2)\,\mathrm{d}u=\sqrt{\frac\pi8}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos(x)}{\sqrt{x}}\mathrm{d}x=\sqrt{\frac\pi2}
$$

---

**Alternate Approach**

As a check, we can use contour integration to show that since $\frac{e^{iz}}{\sqrt{z}}$ has no singularities in the plane minus the negative real axis, we have
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty\frac{\cos(x)}{\sqrt{x}}\mathrm{d}x
&=\mathrm{Re}\left(\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{ix}}{\sqrt{x}}\mathrm{d}x\right)\\
&=\mathrm{Re}\left(\frac{1+i}{\sqrt2}\int_0^\infty\frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{x}}\mathrm{d}x\right)\\
&=\frac1{\sqrt2}\Gamma\left(\frac12\right)\\
&=\sqrt{\frac\pi2}
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=u^2$ and substitute. It's straightforward once you know the Fresnel integral you mentioned.

Comment: Then you get $\frac{cos(t^2)}{t}dt^2$ as noted below which doesn't converge as far as I can tell.

Comment: The way I see it is: Let $x=t^2$, say (instead of $u$). Then $dx=2t\, dt$ Now when $x=0$, $t=0$, and when $x=\infty$, $t=\infty$. So the new limits in the $t$-integral are the same as the old ones. Next $$\int_{0}^\infty \frac{\cos x}{\sqrt{x}}\, dx=\int_{0}^\infty \frac{\cos t^2}{t}\,(2t\, dt) = 2\int_{0}^\infty \cos{t^2}\, dt.$$ So, my point is that IF you know about the Fresnel integral then you are done, but if you want to derive the Fresnel integral formula then that is another question. Maybe I misunderstood your question!?

Comment: Nope! You got it 100%, I'm just feeling especially sleepy today. ;) Thanks you!

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{\cos x}{\sqrt{x}}dx=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{cos t^2}{t}dt^2$$

Comment: If there's really $\;dt^2\;$ there then both integrals are exactly the same, both their value and, as far as I can see, the difficulty to evaluate them.

Comment: you forgot to see that $dx= 2u\, du$ so the u's cancel leaving you with  twice the Fresnel integral.

Comment: If you use the substitution $x = t^2,$ then you must replace $dx$ with $2t\,dt$ to get $2\int \cos(t^2) \,dt$. Please correct, or delete, your answer.

Comment: @Timbuc Maybe the problem is symbolic!? $dt^2$ as you have it means $d(t^2)$ which is $2t\, dt$, if you want to think of this as differentials (but you shouldn't). Anyhow the point is you don't get $dt^2$ but $2t\, dt$.

Comment: @Angelo As I see this answer is precisely as a *symbolic* substitution, and certainly **not** a mathematical one: Road is simply substituting *symbolically* $\;x\to t^2\;$ , which yields a correct integral on the right (under this assumption!) but just as difficult to solve as the original one. Of course, substituting as in integral calculus we get at once $\;x=u^2\implies dx =2udu\;$ , as you mention.

Comment: so are you more interested in the Fresnel integral evaluation or did you assume that?