# How to Solve $\int\sin(x^2)dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, math-software

I want to Solve $\int\sin x^2dx$ in Mathematica and want to get step by step solution
I am getting these results:

[image]

Comment: Please format your question correctly.

Comment: It cannot be integrated in term of elementary functions.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Evaluating $\int_0^\infty \sin x^2\, dx$ with real methods?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/187729/evaluating-int-0-infty-sin-x2-dx-with-real-methods)  It has all the step-by-step methods you should need.

Answer (score 1):

Try: `WolframAlpha["Integrate sin(x^2)"]`
There is no way for Mathematica to show step by step solutions.