# Finding a absolutely integrable function $f$ such that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)\neq 0$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, convergence-divergence

> Find a function $f : \Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb R  $ such that $\int_\Bbb R |f(x)|dx < \infty  $ but for x $ \rightarrow \infty$, $f(x)\not\rightarrow 0$.

Is there a way of generating such functions?  I have just tried various functions, but have been unable to find any that satisfy both conditions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use a function that is piecewise either zero or one. Make the pieces where it is one smaller and smaller as you go to infinity

Comment: Related: [Do integrable functions vanish at infinity?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2132739/do-integrable-functions-vanish-at-infinity)

Comment: If $f$ has a limit, then it must be zero. So, such functions do not have a limit.

Comment: @Jack: The post you've linked to even realizes that your statement isn't true (e.g., you can certainly have continuous functions that don't have limit $0$). If we add the hypothesis that $f$ is monotone, then your claim is true.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I should delete my comment now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $n\in \Bbb N$ let $f_n(x)=1-n^2|x-n|$, and let 
$$f(x)=\max\{0,\max\{\,f_n(x)\mid n\in\Bbb N\,\} \}$$
Then $f$ is continuous, $\int_{\Bbb R}|f(x)|\mathrm dx\le\sum \frac 1{n^2}=\frac{\pi^2}6$, and $f(x)\not\to 0$ as $x\to\infty$

---

With $f_n(x)=n\cdot(1-n^3|x-n|)$, the resulting $f$ is additionally unbounded.

Answer (score 4):

One such example is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n\cdot \chi_{(n,n+1/n^3)}.$

Answer (score 0):

Consider the sequence $f_n=e^{\frac{-x}{n}}sin(x^2)$. The pointwise limit is $sin(x^2)$ and $\int_{\mathbb{R}}sin(x^2)dx=\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}$. Note this function is continuous on all of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Whilst this is true, the question asks for $ \int_\Bbb R |f(x)|dx $ and $ \int_\Bbb R |sin(x^2)|dx $ is divergent.