# Using Euler's formula to evaluate $\int_0^{\infty} \sin(x^2)dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

We let
$$
I = \int_0^{\infty} \sin(x^2)dx
$$
In other terms
$$
I = \int_0^{\infty} \Im\left(e^{ix^2}\right)dx = \Im \left(\int_0^{\infty} e^{ix^2} dx\right)
$$
We let
$$
J = \int_0^{\infty} e^{ix^2}dx
$$
This looks like the gaussian integral so using the standard technique of conversion to polar coordinates we have
$$
J^2 = \left( \int_0^{\infty} e^{ix^2}dx \right)\cdot\left( \int_0^{\infty} e^{iy^2}dy \right) = \iint_{\mathbb{R}^2} e^{i(x^2+y^2)}dA
$$
Converting:
$$
\begin{cases}
r^2 = x^2 + y^2 \\
dA = r \, dr d\theta
\end{cases}
$$
we obtain
$$
J^2 = \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^\infty re^{ir^2} \, dr d\theta
$$
Evaluating and simplifying:
$$
J^2 = \frac{\pi}{i} \left[e^{ir^2} \right]_0^\infty
$$
Does this diverge? What can i do here, because I am pretty sure that $I$ converges? Thanks

Comment: Maybe helpful: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/187729/evaluating-int-0-infty-sin-x2-dx-with-real-methods

Answer (score 3):

$$\cos \left(x^2\right)+i \sin \left(x^2\right)=e^{ix^2}$$
$$\int_0^{\infty}e^{ix^2}\,dx=\left[-\frac{(1+i) \sqrt{\pi } \text{erf}\left(-\frac{(1-i) x}{\sqrt{2}}\right)}{2 \sqrt{2}}\right]_0^{\infty}=\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\right) \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}}$$
$$\int_0^{\infty}\sin(x^2)\,dx=\text{Im}\left(\int_0^{\infty}e^{ix^2}\,dx\right)=\text{Im}\left[\left(\frac{1}{2}+\frac{i}{2}\right) \sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}}\right]=\frac{1}{2}\sqrt{\frac{\pi }{2}}$$