# How to compute the integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\,dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

How to compute the integral $\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\,dx$ using polar coordinates?

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/429632/gaussian-integral

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/q/105220/5531 and http://math.stackexchange.com/q/34767/5531 and http://math.stackexchange.com/q/390850/5531 .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: Let $I=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\,dx.$ Then $$I^2=\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\,dx\right)\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-y^2}\,dy\right)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}e^{-y^2}\,dx\,dy=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(x^2+y^2)}\,dx\,dy.$$ Now switch to polar coordinates.

Answer (score 2):

The usual tear-free approach is to write $$\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\,dx\right)^2=\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-x^2}\,dx\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-y^2}\,dy=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(x^2+y^2)}\,dx\,dy$$ and change to polar coordinates.

Comment: What allows one to bring the integrals together? Is it fubini's theorem or something else?