# solving the integral of $e^{x^2}$

Tags: calculus, indefinite-integrals

How to solve following integral?

Any hints for the above integral ?

$$\int{e^{x^2}} dx =?$$

I use change of variable $t=x^{2}$. so,
$$\frac{1}{2}\int{\frac{e^{t}}{t^{\frac{1}{2}}}dt}$$

But I could not solve it!

thanks.

Comment: This is an integral wich cannot be expressed in terms of standard functions.

Comment: There is no closed form, maybe you are looking for: $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-x^2}dx=\sqrt{\pi}$$ Which can be derivated by using polar coordinates on: $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}e^{-(x^2+y^2)}dx\:dy$$

Comment: See [error function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function), [Liouville's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(differential_algebra)), and the [Risch algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm).

Comment: Is this really not a duplicate of a previous question?

Comment: See [Dawson function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dawson_function) and [this article](http://cs.smu.ca/~dawson/Poisson.pdf), which I found in an answer to [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/105220/generalizing-the-trick-for-integrating-int-infty-infty-e-x2-mathrm-dx). Not the same Dawson, by the way.

Answer (score 3):

The integral which you describe has no [closed form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed-form_expression) which is to say that it cannot be expressed in elementary functions.

For example, you can express $\int x^2 \mathrm{d}x$ in elementary functions such as $\frac{x^3}{3} +C$. However, the indefinite integral from $(-\infty,\infty)$ does exist and it is $\sqrt{\pi}$ so explicitly:

$$\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} e^{-x^2} = \sqrt{\pi}$$

Note the difference in your integral and in the integral above, there is a negative sign in the one above. The integral you have does not converge for the specified bounds.

Also look at [Risch Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm) and the [ERF Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function).

Answer (score 1):

$\int e^{x^2}~dx$

$=\int\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{x^{2n}}{n!}dx$

$=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\dfrac{x^{2n+1}}{n!(2n+1)}+C$